Faced or unfaced insulation for exterior wall bathroom
I am in Colorado and trying to figure out how to properly insulate the exterior wall behind the shower backer and tile. My understanding is that will be a vapor barrier. The exterior is wood siding with paper backing. This is how they previously did it.  What is the appropriate method?

